# Property Grid Collection Member name

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Is there a way to edit the Collection editor and what certain values are displayed as. The Members of my collection when displaying it to the user I would like a more user friendly name rather that the solution name plus the class as the name displayed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's better to share some code to reproduce the problem. Usually overriding `ToString` method of your class will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "... solution name plus the class name ..." and tagged your question with "propertygrid". I assume you are having Design-time problem in a WindowsFormsApplication project. See if following example can help you.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    // Example custom control
    [Docking(System.Windows.Forms.DockingBehavior.Ask)]
    class MyControl : Control
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        // Example array property
        [Editor(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public MyObject[] MyObjectArray
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    // This class requires System.Design assembly to be included in the project
    class MyCollectionEditor : System.ComponentModel.Design.ArrayEditor
    {
        public MyCollectionEditor(Type type)
            : base(type)
        {
        }

        protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
        {
            Form form = base.CreateCollectionForm();
            form.Text = "Here you can put your User Friendly Display Text";
            return form as CollectionForm;
        }
    }

    // Example object
    public class MyObject
    {

        // Following Reza Aghaei's comment I added overridden method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Friendly name";
        }

        [DisplayName("Friendly property name")]
        public string Text
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And please provide more information what you are trying to do.